# python only runs once in IDE upon using sys module

Tags: python, spyder, sys

```
import re
import os
import sys

data_record=re.compile('(.{4}) (.{7}) (.{3}-.{4}-.{1}|.{10}) (\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (\d{1,3}[a-z]{1,8})([ ]{8}.+)') 
KYC= open(r"C:\path\Untitled.txt")
#head=list(islice(KYC, 10))
#print head

KYCapr2017=sys.stdout=open("KYC-apr2017.txt","w")
for line in KYC:
matchData=data_record.match(line)
if matchData:
    print (matchData.group(1).strip() + ","
    + matchData.group(2).strip() + ","
    + matchData.group(3).strip() + ","
    + matchData.group(4).strip() + ","
    + matchData.group(5).strip() + ","
    + matchData.group(6).strip() + ","
    + matchData.group(7).strip()
    )
sys.stdout.close()
```

Prior to adding the lines using the module 'sys', I was able to run the code above consistently in Spyder using F5. Since adding those lines (which saves the print output to a txt file), it only runs once. To run it again, I must restart spyder. How come?

Comment: Why in the world are you messing with `sys.stdout`?  Call `.write()` on your output file to send data to it.

Comment: can you write a generic code to show me the form of using print & .write()? I am very new to this. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `print(...)`, it would be `KYCapr2017.write(...)`.